# jQuery tree from select list (options) with checkboxes. possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am looking for a jQuery plugin/script to make something like this:

[example](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html#tree3)

[image]

From what I have at the moment:

```
<select name="">
    <option disabled="disabled" value="1">Category A</option>
       <option value="2">Category A1</option>
       <option value="3">Category A2</option>
       <option value="4">Category A3</option>

    <option disabled="disabled" value="5">Category B</option>
       <option value="6">Category B1</option>
       <option value="7">Category B2</option>
       <option value="8">Category B3</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible? Or I must somehow change from SELECT to UL and OPTIONS to LI?

Answer (score 1):

yes, `UL`, `OL` and child `IL` are the norm for creating a 'treeview'.

the examples you've linked to also `UL` and `LI`.

use a browser like Chrome and right click the element on the page to see the HTML, you'll learn lots!

Answer (score 0):

> I must somehow change from SELECT to UL and OPTIONS to LI?

If you want something that complex-ish a `select` \ `option` construct is not going to suffice, let alone would generate valid HTML due to the limited amount of elements you can embed within an `option`.

I think you will need to look into `ul` `li` sets.

---

**How has Dynatree done it?**

---

If you check the source of the example page you linked you see the below, showing you exactly the elements used to create it, using `ul` `li` sets as well as `spans` as top-level elemtns for sub `ul` \ `li` elements.

In addition within the `span` sets you find more `spans` with each having a class. Those classes use CSS to inject the images for the folder, expanders as well as the checkboxes from the same sprite-sheet.

Using the below data from the HTML and CSS should get you started into the right direction.

Here is the HTML of one of the trees:

```
<ul class="dynatree-container" style="">
    <li class=""><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-c"><span class="dynatree-connector"></span><span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title" title="Look, a tool tip!">item1 with key and tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class=""><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-selected dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-c"><span class="dynatree-connector"></span><span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title">item2: selected on init</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class=""><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-has-children dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf"><span class="dynatree-expander"></span><span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Folder</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="dynatree-lastsib"><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-expanded dynatree-has-children dynatree-lastsib dynatree-exp-el dynatree-ico-e"><span class="dynatree-expander"></span><span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Document with some children (expanded on init)</a>
        </span>
        <ul style="">
            <li class=""><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-has-children dynatree-active dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-c"><span class="dynatree-expander"></span><span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Sub-item 4.1 (active on init)</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class=""><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-has-children dynatree-selected dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-c"><span class="dynatree-expander"></span><span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Sub-item 4.2 (selected on init)</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class=""><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-c"><span class="dynatree-connector"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Sub-item 4.3 (hideCheckbox)</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="dynatree-lastsib"><span class="dynatree-node dynatree-lastsib dynatree-exp-cl dynatree-ico-c"><span class="dynatree-connector"></span><span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span><span class="dynatree-icon"></span><a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Sub-item 4.4 (unselectable)</a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Below is some of [**the CSS**](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/src/skin/ui.dynatree.css) used for the above HTML.

For the check-boxes `dynatree-checkbox`, icons `dynatree-icon` and expanders `dynatree-expander` classes this CSS is used pointing to the same sprite-sheet, the only thing changing is the position on the sheet selecting the image used:

```
span.dynatree-empty,
span.dynatree-vline,
span.dynatree-connector,
span.dynatree-expander,
span.dynatree-icon,
span.dynatree-checkbox,
span.dynatree-radio,
span.dynatree-drag-helper-img,
#dynatree-drop-marker
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
/*  display: -moz-inline-box; /* @ FF 1+2 removed for issue 221 */
/*  -moz-box-align: start; /* issue 221 */
    display: inline-block; /* Required to make a span sizeable */
    vertical-align: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    background-image: url("icons.gif");
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not stylize SELECT element to tree structure, how in example.
And In your case, you can select only one item. But you can create tree structure by UL and LI-s based on your SELECT element and hide SELECT element for storing selected item in tree structure.